# System.Web.Mvc could not laod when publishing silverlight to discountasp.net

Tags: silverlight, deployment

I made a simple silverlight web application that just has one button filling up the whole page.  It publishes fine to discountasp.net, but when I try to access my website, it says it could not load the file or assembly System.Web.Mvc.  I don't even see this in my silverlight project references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your MVC project, expand the references folder. Then click on System.Web.MVC and in the properties dialog, set "Copy Local" to true. You may need to do this for System.Web.Routing and System.Web.Abstractions as well. Then Publish your website, select FTP and enter your DiscountAP.net FTP address and username and password. Set passive mode to true.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like one of your assemblies is referencing the MVC dll. This will be in the GAC on discountasp.net. Download and install the MVC binaries on the webserver you are using and the problem will go away.

Although I am not sure why your site is looking for them. Check the web.config for assembly references.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am unsure why it is looking for it either.  Nothing is in web.config regarding System.Web.Mvc.  I have no idea how toi install the mvc binaries on discountasp.net, lol.  I am new to this.